# How can I disable the confirmation pop-up when uninstalling an app?

Tags: applications, settings, uninstallation, popup

I have multiple apps that I want to uninstall but it becomes really tedious having to sit and watch as each individual one uninstalls and confirm deletion one at a time.
I have a Samsung a50

Comment: Use command-line instead. Confirmation is not asked from there.